# Php validation not working. Even with good data (closed)

Tags: php, validation

For my website i want to have registration. And everything goes well until it's time for validation. So, i have to this all in different files (validation in validation.php, registration in registration.php and registration form in registrationForm.php). In registration.php i have something like this:

```php
<?php

    session_start();

    include 'validation.php';
    include "mail.php";
    include 'dbConnection/dbconn.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
        $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        //sendMail("test", "test");

        if (validateName($name) && validateSurname($surname) && validateEmail($email) && validatePassword($password1) && validateUsername($username) && checkIfPasswordsAreMatching($password1, $password2)) {
            echo "Worked";
        } else {
            echo "Not worked";
            header("Location: registrationForm.php");
        }

    } else {
        header("Location: registrationForm.php");
    }

?>
```

And my problem is that no matter if i put good data or completely wrong data my validation always says that it's wrong.

Here is my validation code (validation.php):

```php
<?php

    session_start();

    $allChecked = true;

    function validateName($string) {

        if (strlen($string) < 2) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['nameError'] = "Your name is too short. It has to be at least 2 characters long.";
        }

        if (preg_match('[\W]', $string)) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['nameError'] = "Your name cannot contain any special character.";
        }

        return $string;

    }

    function validatePassword($string) {

        if (strlen($string) < 8 || strlen($string) > 20) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['passwordError'] = "Your password must be between 8 and 20 characters long.";
        }

        if (preg_match('/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]/', $string) == false) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['passwordError'] = "Your password must contain at least 1 big letter, 1 special character, 1 number and 1 small letter.";
        }

        return $string;

    }

    function validateSurname($string) {

        if (strlen($string) < 2) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['surnameError'] = "Your surname is too short. It has to be at least 2 characters long.";
        }

        if (preg_match('[\W]', $string)) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['surnameError'] = "Your surname cannot contain any special character.";
        }

        return $string;

    }

    function validateUsername($string) {

        if (strlen($string) < 2 || strlen($string) > 20) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['usernameError'] = "Your username must be between 2 and 20 characters";
        }

        /*
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '$string'";
        $sql = $conn->query($sql);
        $nameExists = $result->fetch();
        if($nameExists) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['usernameError'] = "Name is already taken";
        }
        */

        return $string;

    }

    function validateEmail($string) {

        $em = filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if (!$em){
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['emailError'] = "Your email has to be valid.";
        }

        /*
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE mail = '$string'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $emailExists = $result->fetch();
        if($emailExists) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['emailError'] = "Email is already taken";
        }
        */

        return $allChecked;

    }

    function checkIfPasswordsAreMatching($password1, $password2) {
        if ($password2 != $password1) {
            $allChecked = false;
            $_SESSION['passwordError'] = "Passwords must be the same";
        }

        return $allChecked;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Seems you actually want the function to return `boolean` instead of `string`

Comment: Also, `$allChecked` does not exist in the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of your functions, so it's going to throw a warning.

Comment: i changed $string to $allChecked but now again even if i put correct data it still redirects me back to registration form. And i don't know why my errors don't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of your `return` statements check `$allChecked` and if it has NOT been set return true instead of `$allChecked`.

```
return (isset($allChecked) ? $allChecked : true);
```

Comment: but i have to return ```$allChecked``` because i have to check if validation was ok. When something is not ok within validation process, it automaticlly sets ```$allChecked``` to false

Comment: You are returning it ... if something failed. It's only a true/false indicator and if validation did NOT fail you aren't returning a true flag like you need to if nothing failed. Setting it before all of the functions does NOT work because of variable scope. Each of the functions can not "see" it.

Comment: ok after change it works but i get error that my surname is less than 2 characters long even if type 10 characters

Comment: ok i just had to adjust some things and now it works. Thanks for help ;)

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions `validateName`, `validateSurname`, `validatePassword`, `validateUsername` you are returning the original string instead of validation result. In `validateEmail` and `checkIfPasswordsAreMatching` you are returning $allChecked but it's not initialized with value if all checks are passed so `null` is returned instead.

You should rewrite your validation functions to look like this

```
function validateName($string) {
    if (strlen($string) < 2) {
        $_SESSION['nameError'] = "Your name is too short. It has to be at least 2 characters long.";
        return false;
    }

    if (preg_match('[\W]', $string)) {
        $_SESSION['nameError'] = "Your name cannot contain any special character.";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: i have rewrited functions so they look like example above but still it redirects me back to registration form when data is good. And my errors which i set i session doesn't show up

Comment: Can you edit your question and add html code of your form to the question?